# Rspec test fails missing template format issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, tdd, rspec, integration-testing

I am trying to implement some integration tests for my application to test a voting system I have in place but have run into some problems.  First off, here is the test code I am trying to get to pass:

```
describe "vote_up_user" do

it "should update the user rating" do
  click_link "user_up_arrow"
  response.should have_selector("#user_rating", :content => "1")
end
end
```

Here is the link that gets clicked:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("uparrowbig.png"), vote_up_user_path(@user), :method => :post,
        :id => "user_up_arrow", :class => "arrow", :remote => true %>
```

The corresponding action:

```
respond_to :html, :js

def vote_up_user
  @voted_on_user = User.find(params[:id])
  current_user.vote_exclusively_for(@voted_on_user)
  respond_with(@voted_on_user, :location => user_path(@voted_on_user))
end
```

and in case anyone is interested the corresponding votes/vote_up_user.js.erb:

```
$("user_rating").update('<%= @voted_on_user.plusminus.to_s %>')
$("user_up_arrow").update('<%= image_tag("uparrowbigselect.png") %>')
$("user_down_arrow").update('<%= image_tag("downarrowbig.png") %>')
```

My problem is that I keep failing at the click_link line with the following error:

```
 Missing template votes/vote_up_user with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}
```

I can understand why this is failing as I do not have a template that is html.erb in the specified path.  I actually have a js.erb file instead as this is an AJAX call, but this is not included in the :formats array and thus is not found.  My question is then, what would be the best way to ensure that the :js format is search for when the integration test clicks on the link?  Is this something I can simply adjust in the test or will I need to add it to the link helper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the reason it's not working is that RSpec alone can't test Javascript.

When you add `remote => true` to a link, it only adds `data-remote="true"` as an attribute of the link, which doesn't mean anything without Javascript.  That's why you see in your error `:formats=>[:html]`.  It is only going to look for html views.  In order for Rails to request the .js.erb view by default, you either need to have the .js on the end of the URL that it is requesting or actually use Javascript to request the page.

To get Javascript to actually run in your tests, you need to use something like Capybara.  When you run your test, you'll actually see your browser start up and it will run your test actually in the browser.

If this is what you want to do, I would recommend watching Ryan Bates' recent Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara

**Update based on comments**

`respond_with` will only redirect to the location you specify on POST, PUT, or DELETE requests.  While you have `:method => :post` in the link, links will always generate GET requests when Javascript is disabled (since you're not using AJAX).  Without Javascript, the only way to generate a POST request is with a form tag.

If you want it to degrade gracefully in this situation, you should either create an html view for these situations or put a block after the `respond_with` like this:

```
respond_with(@voted_on_user, :location => user_path(@voted_on_user)) do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to user_path(@voted_on_user) }
end`
```

Comment: thanks for the link i will be sure to check that out.  i was wondering myself if this had an affect on the test and its certainly possible.  however the goal of this test is not necessarily to test the javascript, and if i understand correctly as it stands now this test would mimick a browser with no javascript enabled (dont quote me on that).  in any case shouldnt the controller action still render the html instead of throwing an error?  i have another situation where i post a form instead of using a link and it seems to work fine in that case - could that make a difference as well?

Comment: Yes, you're right.  It's mimicking a browser with no javascript enabled.  Since, no javascript is enabled, it will be looking for the .html.erb view.  Since you don't have one, it is throwing the error.  The only way that Rails knows to render the .js.erb file is if you put .js on the end of the URL or the request headers contain something like this: `Accept: text/javascript, application/javascript` which happens by default when you actually run Javascript and execute the AJAX.

Comment: If you don't want to test the javascript, then rather than clicking on the link, you could just test that the link has the correct URL and `data-remote` attribute.  Then, just request the URL with .js on the end of it (eg. `get '/user/23/vote_user_up.js'`).

Comment: its not so much testing the javascript vs testing the html as opposed to testing the situation that someone with javascript disable clicks on the link (hope that made sense).  since i have respond_with(@voted_on_user, :location => user_path(@voted_on_user)) in my controller i was under the impression that a non javascript request should degrade gracefully and simply redirect to the specified location

Comment: OK, I think I understand.  I think I got confused when you said, "what would be the best way to ensure that the :js format is search for."  If you're testing what happens when someone has Javascript disabled, hopefully it never requests the js format.  Anyways, I updated my answer above to hopefully help a little better now that I think I understand your question better.

Comment: sorry i can see the confusion.  i was under the assumption that the lack of graceful degradation needed to be fixed by adding to the :formats array, hence why i asked for a way to include the :js format.  your way however works perfectly and seems a lot less hacky then anything else i was going to try.  thanks!